# Writing the Yang-Mills topological charge using differential forms

Tags: quantum-field-theory, differential-geometry, yang-mills

I have a very pedestrian knowledge of differential forms and I am having some trouble in a derivation. The topological charge $Q$ in Yang-Mills theories is supposed to be
$$
Q=\int{}q(x)d^4x
$$
where
$$
q(x)=\frac{1}{64\pi^2}\epsilon_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}F^a_{\mu\nu}F^{a\mu\nu}
$$
My text https://munsal.files.wordpress.com/2014/10/marino-lectures2014.pdf equation (4.48) says that
$$
q(x)d^4x=\frac{1}{8\pi^2}Tr(F\wedge{}F)
$$
I am trying to prove this. My attempt is the following
$$
Tr(F\wedge{}F)=\frac{1}{4}Tr(F_{\mu\nu}F_{\alpha\beta}dx^{\mu}\wedge{}dx^{\nu}\wedge{}dx^{\alpha}\wedge{}dx^{\beta})
$$
$$
\frac{1}{4}Tr(F^a_{\mu\nu}T^aF^b_{\alpha\beta}T^b{}dx^{\mu}\wedge{}dx^{\nu}\wedge{}dx^{\alpha}\wedge{}dx^{\beta})
$$
$$
\frac{1}{8}F^a_{\mu\nu}F^a_{\alpha\beta}dx^{\mu}\wedge{}dx^{\nu}\wedge{}dx^{\alpha}\wedge{}dx^{\beta}
$$
From here on I am stuck. I figure I am missing some key identity. Any tip would be appreciated.

Comment: Just write $\mathrm{d}x^\mu\wedge\mathrm{d}x^\nu\wedge\mathrm{d}x^\alpha\wedge\mathrm{d}x^{\beta} = \epsilon^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}\mathrm{d}^4 x$ and you're done.

Comment: Hint: There is only one four-form in four dimensions.

Comment: @Nephente Perhaps you mean that the space formed by 4-forms in dimension 4 is 1-dimensional?